# How can I safely increase size of sda2 with sda

Tags: centos

First of all, I am a total rookie when the topic is server, I can do small things on it but often bump into things that I can't manage.

My current problem is regarding space in the server, which I don't understand very much.

https://i.ibb.co/MsmdBMc/space-server.png

I can see through `lsblk` command that in my `sda` I have a size of 200GB available, which I can imagine it is shared among `sda1` and `sda2`, but only 20GB are being allocated.

I saw some posts mentioning how to do it but most of them say that I might lose info in the process. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/765302/how-to-move-disk-space-from-centos-home-to-centos-root) is very similar to the problem that I am facing at the moment, but I am a bit afraid that I might crack something in the process.

Is this procedure fallible? And Can I do it from the `sda` directly to the `sda2`? I don't know why I can't see the full 200gb summed in `sda1` and `sda2`.

In my understanding, this would be it:

1. Unmount `sda` with `unmount sda` (I'm very dubious in this step since I can't specify a mount point)
2. Then I should reduce to a specific size with `lvreduce -L 50G sda`
3. And then extend the `sda2` with `lvextend -t -r -l+100%FREE /`

Is this correct? I operate in servers occasionally and with very simple stuff, so, this kind of stuff is a bit scary for me.. honestly speaking.

The server is a CentOS 7.

Comment: In any case, you **have** to do a backup first.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is possibly possible, but you don't quite give enough detail. If sda1 is at the start of the disk then you can extend sda2, however if sda2 is at the end of the disk with sda1 immediately before it then it's not going to be possible without more intrusive moving of data.

Your steps 1,2,3 appear wrong to me. `sda` is the physical drive with `sda1` and `sda2` being the partitions. You can unmount a partition but generally not a drive.

As you've stated that you're not too experienced I'm going to offer a "safer" idea rather than a more technically correct idea.
I'm going to guess that your ultimate aim is to either expand `/` to be larger than 17GB or to create an additional mountpoint for `/home` or similar. Assuming that is the case, you're already using LVM, so just add more space to that and work from there

Use `fdisk`, `gparted` or what ever partition manager you feel most comfortable with and add an additional partition with the remainder of the space and mark the type as `lvm`.

1. Create additional lvm physical partition(s) with `pvcreate /dev/sda3`  (The new partition should be sda3), note you can only have 4 primary partitions, others will need to be logical partitions
2. Add the new physical partition to the volume group `vgextend centos /dev/sda3`
3. Expand your desired logical volume eg `lvextend -L+50G /dev/centos/root`
4. Expand the filesystem (assuming ext2,3,4 here) `resize2fs /dev/centos/root`

Steps 3 and 4 could easily be creating an additional logical volume and creating the filesystem